# Update specific table field on another Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to update specific one id / row on a separate field on another table. how is the logic to that? so far i have this pseudo code sql query.

*table name*: **settings**

*current table*: **aircrafts**

> UPDATE settings SET description id = 4

i need to update id 4 on my database in database `settings`

how can i integrate this code into laravel syntax?

assuming i have this controller

```
    public function editAirReg(Request $request, $id)
{

    $descr = $request->input('descr_id');
    DB::update('update settings set description = ,'$descr', where id = 4',[$name,$id]);
    return redirect('/admin/aircrafts')->with('success', 'Settings Updated');
}
```

and also this view

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\AircraftsController@getdata', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}


   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="settings" value="{{$aircraft->air_line}}">


 {{Form::submit('BIND', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg', 'name'=>'submit'])}}

 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: what is a description here?

Comment: What have you tryed to get this working? Or are you just asking for us to do it for you lol

Comment: @PatrickSimard not that of an intention sir.. i just want to learn laravel.. because im working on a program that was never been familiar to me so i dont have any choice but to ask . sorry for that sir. ive tried some few codes in php but noneof them works so i go with a pseudo code for someone to help me

Comment: @PatrickSimard , there sir ive edited my code .. for now that's what i have the basics of laravel only nothing special

Comment: @DPS , sir check out my edited code, description is whre ill update my data on `id 4`

Comment: @DPS , sir please take a look on my edited code it is now clear thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, getData() doesn't make sense if you're updating something in mysql. It should be called store() or save or whatever you want to call so that the function name is appropriate.

Let's change the form so that it can pass the id to the controller.

```
{ Form::open(array('action' => 'Admin\AircraftsController@getdata', $id)) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('settings', $aircraft->air_line) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

What I did is that change your input to the laravel syntax. Also make sure you pass the id from form to controller. take a look at my example. look where I put $id field.

Now in the controller, this is what you do.

```
$setting = Setting::findOrFail($id); // you must have a model or you can use DB facade
$setting->description = $request->settings; //name that you called it in form
$setting->save();
```

Comment: @Giogi Lagidze, ive tried that before but it didnt work check out my new updated code

Comment: have you changed the form as I told you? update your form as I suggested and let me know. if it doesn't work still, also make sure to update your form here also so that I can look at it.

Comment: hello sir thank you for your response, can you help me on the query statement? because i think that is what im getting missed out. i need to update the `id 4 of description`

Comment: you're not passing id from form to controller. that's the issue.

Comment: yeah. you're right i think i need to select id 4 query

Comment: here i got some code `$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";` hehe but i dont know how to convert it to laravel

Comment: I already showed you the example how you do it.  look at my answer and find the controller section. find($id) gives you the record then you set properties and then you call save()

Comment: yeah but what i have is two table.. your code will not work in my case because it updates selected row like in a crud.,. what i need is when i select any row in my current table then the other table `id = 4` is automatically updating that is why it is an `input type hidden` and its value is fixed